# Converting an array of keys and an array of values into a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays like this:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a simple way in Ruby to convert those arrays into the following hash?

```
{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3 }
```

Here is my way of doing it, but I feel like there should be a built-in method to easily do this.

```
def arrays2hash(keys, values)
  hash = {}
  0.upto(keys.length - 1) do |i|
      hash[keys[i]] = values[i]
  end
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The following works in 1.8.7:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
values = [1, 2, 3]
zipped = keys.zip(values)
=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
Hash[zipped]
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

This appears not to work in older versions of Ruby (1.8.6). The following should be backwards compatible:

```
Hash[*keys.zip(values).flatten]
```

Comment: So Hash[keys.zip(values)] then?

Comment: Thanks, the zip method is probably what I need... but the "Hash[zipped]" part is giving me an error in Ruby 1.8.6: "ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash". And I just can't figure out another simple way of changing 'zipped' into a hash...

Comment: Hmm. I'm using 1.8.7. It looks like this might have been introduced in 1.8.7. I'll edit the answer for a backwards-compatible version.

Comment: This is great. Shame that you have to * and flatten the zip in older versions of Ruby though :(

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to use each_with_index:

```
hash = {}
keys.each_with_index { |key, index| hash[key] = values[index] }

hash # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Answer (score 10):

The same can be done using [`Array#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method. If you are using Ruby version >= **2.1**, you can take the advantage of the method [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h), otherwise use your old friend, [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3]
[keys, values].transpose.to_h
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
Hash[[keys, values].transpose]
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Comment: Fantastic stuff. Thanks. I did a little edit to cleanup the code and highlight which one you use, depending on the version of Ruby you have.

Comment: Any idea if this is preferable to the `.zip` method shown below? e.g. more performant, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this way the latter one `d` will overwrite the former one `c`

```
irb(main):001:0>  hash = Hash[[[1,2,3,3], ['a','b','c','d']].transpose]
=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"d"}
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

In current Ruby `keys.zip(values).to_h` is probably the most readable short solution.

References:

- [`Array#zip`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Array.html#method-i-zip)
- [`Array#to_h`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h)