# Better way to loop through a set of hashes assigning array values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, file, uploading

I am trying to insert data into Postgres. I have an array of data and I am trying to assign each column a value of the array. Here is an example.

```
pg_insert = ['12/09/2015', 41, 'test account', '41.0']
Table.create([date: pg_insert[0],
            account_number: pg_insert[1],
            account_name: pg_insert[2],
            values: pg_insert[3]])
```

Is there a way where I can loop this so I can put i in pg_insert instead of having to type out numbers? I'm not sure how to loop inside of the create() parameter. Is there any way around this?

Any suggestions would be great thanks.

Comment: Just confirming do you really mean `Table.create([...])`?  The `pg_insert` is an Array of Strings, but the argument to :create appears that you meant a Hash.  If it is to be a Hash, I think I have an idea for you...

Comment: Whatever uploads. I think it works both ways.

Comment: Table.create(date: pg_insert[0], account_number: pg_insert[1]) works if that's what you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table.create` is accepting a Hash, I'm sure.

So here is what you can do:

1. Make an Array called `keys` that contains 4 symbols `:date`, `:account_number`, `:account_name`, and `:values`.
2. `pg_insert` is already an Array.
3. Now you can put the two Arrays together to make the Hash you need: `Hash[keys.zip(pg_insert)]`
4. This allows you to call `Table.create` like this:  `Table.create(Hash[keys.zip(pg_insert)])`

Here is the finished code then:

```
keys = [:date, :account_number, :account_name, :values]
pg_insert = ['12/09/2015', 41, 'test account', '41.0']
Table.create(Hash[keys.zip(pg_insert)])  # or Table.create Hash[keys.zip(pg_insert)]  if you don't want so many parentheses.
```

Note that `pg_insert` will always have to be in the same order as `keys`.

You can read more about Array#zip and Hash.new to understand how those work.   This SO link might also be helpful: [Converting an array of keys and an array of values into a hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740732/converting-an-array-of-keys-and-an-array-of-values-into-a-hash-in-ruby)

Comment: Yeah it took me a while to get back to that script, but once I tried it out it did work. Thanks!